# Why is jest not mocking my imported function correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

All I want to do is import a util file that I'm using in my code and mock it so that is returns true or false depending on what I'm testing

so I tried `import * as myModule from 'utils/myFunction'`

inside my util I have

`export const myFunctionName = () => { // does some stuff }`

`const mySpy = jest.spyOn(myModule, 'myFunctionName').mockReturnValue(false)`

but even if I change this to

`const mySpy = jest.spyOn(myModule, 'myFunctionName').mockReturnValue(true)`

when I `console.log(myFunctionName)` in my code it logs out `false` both times

what am I doing wrong and how can I properly mock this named export function to return whatever I want for testing purposes

I've also tried this

```
beforeEach(() => {
    myFunctionName.mockReturnValue(true)
})
```

but then in my tests

`myFunctionName.mockReturnValueOnce(false)`

has no effect, it only changes when I change it in the `beforeEach`

Comment: It's unknown at which time spyOn and console.log are called. But it's unsafe to spy on module object as it's read-only by specs. Use jest.mock.

Comment: ok but I'm having problems with jest.mock as I need a different implementation per test case but jest.mock seems to only mock it once at the top and you cant change it. I also tried jest.domock, same outcome

Comment: You can change the implementation temporarily any moment with `*Once` methods.

Comment: @EstusFlask see added code to show what else I've tried

Comment: It's unknown at which time spyOn and console.log are called, as I said. This is likely the case. The function obviously should be mocked before it's called. If it's expected to be called multiple times, there should be multiple mockReturnValueOnce.